# From an explicit function to an implicit one

Tags: real-analysis, functions, equivalence-relations, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

I've seen a lot of people asking questions about how to go from an implicit expression and get an explicit function.
I wonder if we can do the opposite: starting with an explicit function $d(x,y)$ and write this in a implicit form.
I think we should simply consider 
$$f(x,y,z)= z- d(x,y)$$
but I'm not sure if this is the idea behind the problem.